# Software Validation

Tags: validation, testing

I have an interview soon where basic knowledge of Software Validation would be an advantage. I started researching it and I found something called Software Testing,- is this the same thing?

Does anyone know a good way to learn Software Validation by doing, not reading/watching?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software validation is a part of software testing. If you define validation it would be, "The process of evaluating software during or at the end of the development process to determine whether it satisfies specified business requirements."[1]

[1] http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/verification-vs-validation/

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to 'Software Testing'. You are validating/testing the developed software against functional requirements.

Eg :  Say You need to validate/test gmail login page.

You start validating login page with various permutations and combinations of username and passwd.

This is one simple validation or testing example which you can try.